# How to get time value for multiple max/min values in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table contains following values:
[quote_date],[total_time],[supA_demB],[demA_supB],[demB_supA],[supB_demA]

I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT quote_date
  ,min(demA_supB) as MinDemASupB
  ,max(demA_supB) as MaxDemASupB
  ,min(supA_demB) as MinSupADemB
  ,max(supA_demB) as MaxSupADemB
  ,min(demB_supA) as MinDemBSupA
  ,max(demB_supA) as MaxDemBSupA
  ,min(supB_demA) as MinSupBDemA
  ,max(supB_demA) as MaxSupBDemA
  FROM [dbo].[a_b_RatioTable]
  GROUP BY quote_date
```

Is there any way to add total_time value to each mix/max value in this query?
Like:

```
SELECT quote_date
  ,min(demA_supB) as MinDemASupB
  ,something as MinDemASupBTime
  ,max(demA_supB) as MaxDemASupB
  ,something as MinDemASupBTime...
```

Comment: can you show sample records with desired result?

Comment: quote_date MinDemASupB MaxDemASupB MinSupADemB MaxSupADemB MinDemBSupA MaxDemBSupA MinSupBDemA MaxSupBDemA
1 2006-01-01 0.0104795321637427 0.0107321428571429 0.0105066977285964 0.0108878092939046 91.8458408855336 95.1773835920177 93.1780366056572 95.4241071428571

Here is the first row of my query I wonder if it is possible to add total_time columns for each value

Comment: You think this is readable? Just try.

Comment: quote_date MinDemASupB    MaxDemASupB
2006-01-01 0.0104795321637427 0.0107321428571429
Sorry don't really know how to edit comments here
This is smaller table results hope it's readable

Comment: can you show sample data your table?

Comment: As I wrote my talbe contains following columns:
[quote_date],[total_time],[supA_demB],[demA_supB],[demB_supA],[supB_demA]
quote_date  - date
total_time - time(7)
the rest are float types,
I want to find min and max of those float numbers dayly. 
This is not a problem, but I want SQL to show me also when(time) each one of mix/max values appeared.

Comment: could you please add example tables from comments to original post and format them properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT quote_date
  ,min(demA_supB) as MinDemASupB
  ,(select total_time from [dbo].[a_b_RatioTable] where quote_date = r.quote_date and demA_supB = min(r.demA_supB)) MinDemASupBTotal
  ,max(demA_supB) as MaxDemASupB
  ,(select total_time from [dbo].[a_b_RatioTable] where quote_date = r.quote_date and demA_supB = max(r.demA_supB)) MaxDemASupBTotal
  ,min(supA_demB) as MinSupADemB
  ,(select total_time from [dbo].[a_b_RatioTable] where quote_date = r.quote_date and supA_demB = min(r.supA_demB)) MinSupADemBTotal
  ,max(supA_demB) as MaxSupADemB
  ,(select total_time from [dbo].[a_b_RatioTable] where quote_date = r.quote_date and supA_demB = max(r.supA_demB)) MaxSupADemBTotal
  ,min(demB_supA) as MinDemBSupA
  .......
  ,max(demB_supA) as MaxDemBSupA
  ,min(supB_demA) as MinSupBDemA
  ,max(supB_demA) as MaxSupBDemA
  FROM [dbo].[a_b_RatioTable] r
  GROUP BY quote_date
```

Note: sub queries may degrade performance.

Comment: Returns error
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: it could happen if your records have two or more same minimum numbers for one quote date. In that case you should decide which total_time to use and apply the logic accordingly.

Comment: Works fine with Top 1 and order by in select, little bit slow though.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another column as total_time. it will work fine.

```
,min(demA_supB) as MinDemASupB
,max(demA_supB) as MaxDemASupB
,min(supA_demB) as MinSupADemB
,max(supA_demB) as MaxSupADemB
,min(demB_supA) as MinDemBSupA
,max(demB_supA) as MaxDemBSupA
,min(supB_demA) as MinSupBDemA
,max(supB_demA) as MaxSupBDemA
,total_time
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a time for each min/max value